# cant pass more than a select-option

Tags: php

here is a piece of a script which drive me crazy

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))  {
$cnt = $_POST['cnt'];

for ($i ='0'; $i <= $cnt; $i++){
    $group[$i] = $_POST['group'];
    $databox[$i] = $_POST['newdata'][$i];
    $cve[$i] = $_POST['cve'][$i];
    $play[$i] = $_POST['play'][$i];
    $cause[$i] = $_POST['cause'][$i];
    }
}
```

=============ENTRY POINT=======================

```
<form method="POST" name="tt" action="#" >
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i <= $cnt; $i++){
[...]

echo "<input type='text' name ='newdata[$i]' value ='$newdata' />
<input type='text' name ='cause[$i]' value ='$newcause' />
<input type='text' name ='play[$i]' value ='$newplay' />
<input type='text' name ='cve[$i]' value = '$newcve' />

<select name='group'>
<option></option>
<option value = 'afb'>1</option>
<option value = 'alc'>2</option>
<option value = 'abd'>3</option>
[...]
<option value = 'ven'>4</option>
<option value = 'nct'>5</option>
</select>";
} 

echo "<input type='hidden' name ='cnt' value= '$cnt' />
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Go' />";
?>
</form>
```

My problem is that whichever option I select only the last chosen is displayed. I tried with

```
$group[$i] = $_POST['group'][$i];
```

but I get the split (a single letter) of "value"
I mean, suppose you select option 4 I get 
    $group[0] = v
    $group[1] = e
    $group[2] = n

Hope you understand what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're submitting your select element as a single element, not an array. Your PHP script is using the index of that single (string) element to get individual characters.

try

```
<select name='group[]'>
```

Comment: I think group[$i] would make it more consistent